# Ping Sound for MS Office Communicator 2007

Tags: audio, microsoft-office, communicator

Is there a way to receive a ping sound within one conversation,  each time one of the parties sends a response?  For instance, hello - ping sound, hello - ping sound, how are you ping sound, i'm fine ping sound, etc.

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

In the Office Communicator Menu, choose **Tools->Options.**

- In the options window, choose **Alerts** from the navigation menu on
  the left. From this menu, you can change whether or not you receive a
  notification if another user adds you as a contact and you can change
  when and how Communicator displays alerts and plays sounds.
- Move on to the **Alerts tab** in the left pane, and select
  **Configure Sounds** option under the Sounds category.
- This will direct you to a dialogue box where you can see the list of
  alert events set with the Communicator program with their respective
  sounds.
- Browse through the events and locate the entry for which you want to
  set a different sound.
- Highlight the event and click on the arrow against Sounds to view the
  available notification sounds such as chord.wav or ding.wav.
- Select the desired sound and click Play to listen to the file. If you
  want to set the sound to play with the notification, click OK, and
  close the Configure Sounds window.
- Click OK in the Office Communicator Options dialogue box to close the
  window as well, and you are done!

[image: ALert]